# How to create a drop down list that displays the quantity from a table in my database?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have a table called Product and I am trying to display the data from the column onHand in a dropbox. Although I need the data to display as a list. So the user can select how many items of the product they want. Currently, it just displays as each value I have in onhand. I have the drop-down bound to a sqldatasource.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list or array or the like and fill it in a loop from 1 to your `onHand` value and assign it to the drop down for the product.